# Unable to click on the image in protractor

Tags: protractor

Network is defined as bing in the start of the code.

```
var imageicon=  $('.netwrokButtonGroup').$$('img').filter((image) =>{
      return image.getAttribute('src').then((attr)=>{
                if(attr.indexOf(Network) !== -1) {
            return attr.click()
            // console.log("last line")
        }}})
```

There are no errors found but the element doesn't get clicked.

Comment: Try placing "debugger" statements inside code blocks to see the output of each execution. Reasons can be that filter doesn't matches of attribute is not same.

Comment: Please review the filter method. I believe the filter function takes a callback that returns a promised boolean. Your method above `(image) => { ...` does not currently do that. Please revise the above. Also I'm not sure what the Variable network is. Is this a string? Please also provide a generic HTML snippet of what you are testing and which image you are trying to click.